# Why does scipy.optimize.curve_fit not fit the data if a large gap exists between two groups of evenly spaced points?

Tags: python, data-analysis, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

So I have a bell shaped distribution of points onto which I would like to fit a gaussian function. sometimes it happens that this bell shape distribution of points is missing some points at the peak of this bell. The distribution and the location of this gap is always symmetric. Without the gap, the curve fitting function performs perfectly fine, the occurrence of this gap however leads to the function to become unable to fit my data. the function which I am using is scipy.optimize.curve_fit with an unbound least squares method. the gaussian function which I am using has the following form:

```
    def gauss_function(self,x, a, b, c):
        x = np.array(x)
        return a*np.exp(-(x.astype(float)-b)**2/(2*c**2))
```

Below you can see a plot of the optimized gaussian fitting my data when no gap is present, the black line is the optimized function and the blue points are the data:

[gaussian function (gauss_tail) being fitted to my data (tail) in the absence of a gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byFpr.png)

And now here is what happens when there is a gap in between my data:
[gaussian function (gauss_tail) being fitted to my data (tail) in the presence of a gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGWxh.png)

any ideas of how to fix this, or why this might be occurring?

I tried adding an additional parameter to the function for the optimizer to fit. specifically I added the y-axis intercept, e:

```
    def gauss_function(self,x, a, b, c, e):
        x = np.array(x)
        return a*np.exp(-(x.astype(float)-b)**2/(2*c**2))+e
```

This didn't solve the problem, instead it made the fitting ot the data which didn't have a gap, worse, as the optimizer now had to fit an additional parameter. The e parameter is in this case not even needed as the data is distributed in such a way that the minimum y value of the data is 0.

But then I had the idea of inputting an initial guess as the p0 attribute for the curve_fit function for the parameters based on functions it had fit before. This worked, but it requies that the first curve in my dataset is one with no gap, and this cannot always be guaranteed.
It would be nice to have a more elegant workaround to this problem.

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Even a rough guess for `p0` is often much better than the default guess, which is all 1s.  For example, you could write some code that estimates the location of the gap, and use the midpoint of the gap as the guess for `b`. And you could try using the maximum of the data as the guess for `a`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser thats a nice suggestion, I was going to do something similar but rather more based on updating the initial guess by taking the average of the parameters.